# How to disable HTTPS on Keycloak

Tags: jboss, wildfly, keycloak

Like in the title: How to disable the requirement of https on Keycloak? Using only the terminal, as I can't log in to the administrator panel, because... there's no https.

Comment: There is no such requirement in keycloak

Comment: How are you launching your keycloak instance? I mean, standalone, docker..

Answer (score 4):

You could change "Require SSL" in Realm settings, Login tab.
The options are

**external requests**

> Keycloak can run out of the box without SSL so long as you stick to
>   private IP addresses like localhost, 127.0.0.1, 10.0.x.x, 192.168.x.x,
>   and 172..16.x.x. If you don’t have SSL/HTTPS configured on the server
>   or you try to access Keycloak over HTTP from a non-private IP adress
>   you will get an error.

**none**

> Keycloak does not require SSL. This should really only be used in
>   development when you are playing around with things.

**all requests**

> Keycloak requires SSL for all IP addresses.

The SSL mode for each realm can be configured in the Keycloak admin console.