# Fix "We're sorry HTTPS required " Keycloak login page

Tags: keycloak

I was facing issue while logging into keycloak from external IP. As soon as i tried to login using administrative console I was presented with a message "We're sorry HTTPS required" . I search for almost all stackoverflow post but only one post was useful .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable HTTPS on Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592284/how-to-disable-https-on-keycloak)

Answer (score -3):

To disable the ssl requirement we can do so by using the below command:

```sh
java -cp /opt/keycloak-4.8.3.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/h2database/h2/main/h2-1.4.193.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url "jdbc:h2:/opt/keycloak-4.8.3.Final/standalone/data/keycloak" -user sa -password sa -sql "update REALM set ssl_required='NONE' where id = 'master'"
```

Make sure you stop the keycloak service first, so that you can update the table.